# Magento mini cart doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9, php, xml, mini-cart

I have an issue with my website. I do not know what's wrong and i forgot what i did last time. The mini cart doesn't update itself when i tried to add product, the mini cart's counts works well, but when i'm trying to view my mini cart, it says "You have no items in your shopping cart."

This is my website :http://sanvanina.com. Please help me, thank you

Comment: If having any custom layout or template mini cart, please revert back to default.

Comment: Try with disabling custom modules one by one

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I did but still doesn't work

Comment: @AnilSuthar I did but still doesn't work. And also i revert back to the default theme (rwd), still no luck. I tried to add ajax mini cart module, but same. What's the possibility of this problem?

Comment: You should debug this file: `\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\checkout\cart\minicart\items.phtml`. Do some `echo` and `exit;` there.

Comment: @AnilSuthar Are you sure? Because i already revert back my theme to default rwd's theme, i mean the whole theme, not just the minicart's template, but it didn't work.

Comment: @AnilSuthar So, i tried to debug items.phtml, i think the problem is $_items because it return an empty array, any idea?

Comment: Go to admin: `System > Configuration > Checkout > Shopping Cart Side Bar`. Check **Maximum Display Recently Added Item(s)**

Comment: @AnilSuthar You just saved my life bro!!!!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad that helps, I have posted a complete answer so that you can accept the solution. :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is, Go to admin: `System > Configuration > Checkout > Shopping Cart Side Bar`. Check **Maximum Display Recently Added Item(s)** and set it's value.

If it's not working, then you should debug this file: `\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\checkout\cart\minicart\items.phtml`. Do some `echo` and `exit;` there